# How to download and edit lambda with AWS explorer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pycharm

I'm trying to use AWS explorer in PyCharm to download and edit an existing lambda function on my AWS account, but I'm unable to find out how to do that.  I've read through all the documentation available on the wiki as well as followed a bunch of tutorials on deploying new lambda functions, but I can't find out how to edit and download existing functions.  I can download the AWS lambda using the console, but I'm not sure how to get this to be editable in my PyCharm project, but this also seems like a workaround anyway.  Is there a way to do this within the AWS Explorer tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, currently (Oct 2019) you can't download a Lambda Function's source and edit it locally. If you know the name of the S3 object where the code is stored, you could pull that file down adn make changes, re-zip it, re-upload it back to S3, force the Lambda to cold-start (change the memory slider) and it will pick up the new code. but this is extremely brittle.

Comment: I'm currently looking at this, it seems like AWS toolkit supports to list all the available Lambda resources, but I couldn't get it working, can someone take a look at my question please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67790447/aws-toolkit-for-pycharm-error-loading-resources-check-log-for-details-lambda

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried cloud9, I find it the best way to work on lambdas, especially if you are working as a team. but the problem with cloud9 is also it seems it's not actively being developed and you have lots of manual work to update SAM and dev tools in there. Anyhow I still recommend cloud9.

Comment: yea, I did checkout cloud 9. Eventually I got pycharm working well and it is awesome! The thing I was missing is each developer should be testing locally and only have one AWS account for production and test.